# Can't use openlayers-3 with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, openlayers-3

I have to include openlayers in a project that I am working on. I have tried both including it in a `ext` folder and by npm.

I am using Webpack in my workflow. On compilation I get the following warning in my console.

`WARNING in ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js
Critical dependencies:
730:1111-1118 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/openlayers/dist/ol.js 730:1111-1118`

Any idea what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that the file you are trying to require is already built and suggesting you that use the main file instead of pre-built. Try to require main file instead of pre-built from dist folder and that should resolve your problem

Comment: It's actually the js file from the /dist folder. :s

Comment: It's just a warning so you can ignore it. But there should be a main file also beside dist