# OpenLayers v3 with Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, openlayers-3, uglifyjs

Hello I am currently using OpenLayers v3 with Webpack. It works fine when I am not using UglifyJS. But the moment I added my uglifyJS config, it just won't compile anymore

My UglifyJS config

```
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            sequences: true,
            dead_code: true,
            conditionals: true,
            booleans: true,
            unused: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true,
            drop_console: true
        }
    }),
```

And i get this error

```
from UglifyJs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I am using the `dist/ol.js` file.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39078429/4640499)?

Comment: Different issue @JonatasWalker :/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I load ol3 in my webpack project :

webpack.config.js :

```
...

resolve: {
  alias: {
    openlayers3: "openlayers/dist/ol.js",
  },
},

plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    ol: "openlayers3",
  }),
]

...
```

ProvidePlugin load modules and make them globally available in your app. You don't have to import ol3 in your js files anymore.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin

Comment: But does it add the ol3 library in your main output file, or adds it on demand (when a page needs ol3)?

Comment: Yes, in this way ol3 will be bundled in your main file

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here. Resolved by moving openlayers into its own chunk using CommonsChunkPlugin, then ignoring that chunk in UglifyJsPlugin.

entries:

```
entry: {
    vendor: Object.keys(packageDotJson.dependencies),
    openlayers: ['openlayers'],
    app: './src/index.jsx'
}
```

CommonsChunkPlugin:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ["openlayers", "vendor"],
    minChunks: Infinity,
    filename: "[name].[hash].js"
}),
```

UglifyJsPlugin:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
        warnings: false
    },
    exclude: 'openlayers'
}),
```

Then included in the html template using HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script src="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: openLayers is loaded only when needed then?

Comment: Nope, not really. To get that you'd have to either set up multiple entry points, generating a separate html file for each, or use require.ensure, or use System.import in webpack2